# How to implement a static factory pattern in C++

Tags: c++, static-methods, smart-pointers, factory-pattern

I tried to implement a static factory pattern with a template to a) void writing identical code snippet for each derived class, and b) recycle objects of the same type. The code below compiles but does not work.  Not sure if this was because I used smart pointers.

This is my code:

```
class ObjMgr
{
public:
    static ObjMgr & Instance();
    template <typename T>
    void Register(const char* name) {
        m_creators[name] = &(ObjCreator<T>);
    }
    Abstract &
        GetObj(const string& objTypeCode);

private:
    ObjMgr(void) {};

    template <typename T>
    static shared_ptr<Abstract>& ObjCreator() {
        return move(std::shared_ptr<Abstract> (new T));
    }
    typedef shared_ptr<Abstract>& (*PObjCreator)();
    std::unordered_map<std::string, PObjCreator> m_creators;

    vector< shared_ptr<Abstract> > m_objs;

    //singleton
    static unique_ptr<ObjMgr> m_instance;
    static std::once_flag m_onceFlag;
    ObjMgr(const ObjMgr &) = default;
    ObjMgr& operator=(const ObjMgr &) = default;
};

Abstract& ObjMgr::GetObj(const string& objTypeCode)
{
    const shared_ptr<Abstract>& obj = m_creators[objTypeCode]();
    m_objs.push_back(move(obj));

    return *(m_objs.back());
}
```

The code compiles but at runtime, a null reference was returned by `GetObj`.
In `main()`, a derived type is registered as

```
objMgr.Register<Derived>("Derived");
```

BTW, I used a vector to hold the objects so that I could later recycle the object of the same type.

Could someone tell me what I did wrong and show me how I could correct it?

Comment: *BTW, I used a vector to hold the objects so that I could later recycle the object of the same type.* -- So does this really mean you are holding onto the address of the object that's in the vector to be used for "later recycle"?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: the object was created on stack in `ObjCreator()`.  I simply need to create static variables to hold the objects:

```
template <typename T>
static shared_ptr<Abstract>& ObjCreator() {
    static vector<shared_ptr<Abstract>> objs;
    objs.emplace_back(std::make_shared<T>());
    return (objs.back());
}
```

And then in `ObjMgr` I will do the bookkeeping to see if an object of a particular type already exists so I can recycle it.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your Register(const char* name) method and the unordered_map<string, ...> are in conflict. Change the unordered_map to a unordered_map<const char*, ...> instead.

I couldn't get your code to compile.

The following code works:

Note that the usual way I've done this is to use a Singleton<T> template since it seems you want to always get the same instance.

If you want to be able to return different instances, then change the code in ObjectManager::CreatorFunc so that the 'instance' variable is not static, but rather a local variable or pass a different CreatorFunc to Register.

stdafx.h:

```
#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
```

cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class Abstract
{
};

template <typename T>
class Singleton : public Abstract
{
private:
    static T* m_singleton;

public:
    static T& Instance()
    {
        if (m_singleton == 0)
        {
            m_singleton = new T();
        }
        return *m_singleton;
    }
};

template <typename T> T* Singleton<T>::m_singleton;

class ObjectManager : public Singleton<ObjectManager>
{
private:
    typedef Abstract& (*CreatorFuncType)();
    std::unordered_map<const char*, CreatorFuncType> m_creators;

    template <typename T>
    static T& CreatorFunc()
    {
        static T* const instance = new T();
        return *instance;
    }

public:
    template <typename T>
    void Register(const char* name, CreatorFuncType creator = (CreatorFuncType)CreatorFunc<T>)
    {
        m_creators[name] = creator == 0 ? (CreatorFuncType)Singleton<T>::Instance : creator;
    }

    Abstract& ObjectManager::GetObj(const char* name)
    {
        CreatorFuncType creator = m_creators[name];
        return (creator)();
    }
};

class TestClass : Singleton<TestClass>
{
    static int count;

    int myInstance;
public:

    TestClass()
        : myInstance(++count)
    {
        std::cout << "hello in test class ctor instance #" << myInstance << std::endl;
    }

    void TestFunc()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm in the test func with instance #" << myInstance << std::endl;
    }
};

int TestClass::count = 0;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ObjectManager::Instance().Register<TestClass>("TestClass");
    TestClass &tc = (TestClass&)ObjectManager::Instance().GetObj("TestClass");
    TestClass &tc2 = (TestClass&)ObjectManager::Instance().GetObj("TestClass");

    std::cout << "tc == tc2 is " << (&tc == &tc2 ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "tc.... ";
    tc.TestFunc();
    std::cout << "tc2... ";
    tc2.TestFunc();

    char buf[100];
    std::cin >> buf;
    return 0;
}
```